# Selenium Click() doesn't work when ChromeOptions are loaded

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm in the process of learning selenium, so here is my code (I have googled this for many hours and this is the first time I couldn't find an answer for any of my questions so this is my first asked question). It Launches a Chrome browser goes to www.google.hr types sth in searchbar presses enter then Saves organic and ad search results in WebPageObject ,then clicks on the next page button then repeats the process. The thing is this code works if I instantiate driver = new ChromeDriver(); but not with in this case                                  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);. So with options in the constructor it goes to the first search results page and saves the same page 3 times. In debug mode I watched and in WPO there is IWebElement NextPageButton with the correct URL and everything.

```
public static IWebDriver driver;
List<WebPageObject> WPOList = new List<WebPageObject>();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Smirglpapir/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
    options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.hr");
    IWebElement seacrhBarElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
    seacrhBarElement.SendKeys("What is the purpouse of life");
    seacrhBarElement.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(4000); // this fixes million errors
        WebPageObject WPO = new WebPageObject(); // Saves 
        WPOList.Add(WPO);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        WPO.nextButton.Last().Click(); // last because it clicks the previous button . 
    }

    class WebPageObject
    {
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public List<IWebElement> nextButton { get; set; }
        public List<string> organicSearchResults { get; set; }
        public List<string> stText { get; set; }

        private List<IWebElement> organicSRElementList = new List<IWebElement>(); 
        public WebPageObject()
        {
            //gets the next button
            nextButton = Form1.driver.FindElements(By.Id("pnnext")).ToList();
            // saves the href
            URL = nextButton.Last().GetAttribute("href");
            // saves the IWebelements of organic seacrh results
            organicSRElementList = Form1.driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("rc")).ToList();
            // stores searchresults in organicSearchResults property (List<string>)
            SaveSearchResults();            
        }

        private void SaveSearchResults()
        {
            stText = new List<string>();
            organicSearchResults = new List<string>();
            foreach (IWebElement IwebEl in organicSRElementList)
            {
                organicSearchResults.Add(IwebEl.Text);
                stText.Add(IwebEl.FindElement(By.ClassName("st")).Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I overcomplicated the question, but this code also doesen't work ;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Smirglpapir\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.hr");
    IWebElement seacrhBarElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
    seacrhBarElement.SendKeys("What is the purpouse of life");
    seacrhBarElement.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    var nextButton = driver.FindElements(By.Id("pnnext"));
    nextButton.Last().Click();
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    nextButton = driver.FindElements(By.Id("pnnext"));
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    nextButton.Last().Click();
}
```

It stays on the same page

Comment: The code for `WebPageObject` would be useful here.

Comment: Thank you, Sorry I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Instead of

```
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Smirglpapir\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
```

You just add for example John_Doe after User Data like this:

```
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Smirglpapir\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\John_Doe");
```

and chrome will create a profile for you automatically in that loaction. Why it doesen't work with a default profile i really don't know.